# Linq to Entities query - find all records with same field value

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am using the following Linq to Entities Query, querying once on a unique field and then finding all records matching on a seperate (foreign key) property:

```
public IEnumerable<User> getUsersInSameCentreAs(String userName)
{
    int? studyCentreId = (from u in _db.Users
                         where u.UserName == userName
                         select u.StudyCentreID).FirstOrDefault();
    return (from u in _db.Users
            where u.StudyCentreID == studyCentreId
            select u).ToList();
    }
```

There must be a clean/single query which will only query the database once to obtain the same result, but my knowledge of linq to entities is letting me down - can anyone see a better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery will solve this:

```
return (from u in _db.Users
        where u.StudyCentreID == (from u2 in _db.Users
                     where u2.UserName == userName
                     select u2.StudyCentreID).FirstOrDefault();
        select u).ToList();
```